# python dict in comma separated csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dictionary

Python dict is in a format like this:

```
'{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}'
```

Notice it use comma to separate different key:value pairs.

The problem is I have a CSV file, which is separate columns by comma too :

```
'
  "id",   "gender",   "age",    "name"
 "001",     "male",    "14",    "{"first":"Mike", "last":"Green"}"
 "002",   "female",    "15",    "{"first":"Kate", "last":"Spear"}"
'
```

When I do
`pandas.read_csv('csvfile.csv', sep = ',', names=["id", "gender", "age", "name"])`

I got:

```
'
  "id",   "gender",   "age",    "name"
 "001",     "male",    "14",    "{"first":"Mike"
 "002",   "female",    "15",    "{"first":"Kate"
'
```

The reason I guess is csv reader regards the comma follows first name in dict as a separator in csv files. Since I only specified 4 columns named " "id",   "gender",   "age",    "name"", so it ignore last names.

Any thoughts or possible solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: How did you produce that file in the first place? The quoting is rather useless too.

Comment: Yes I think they are useless too. This data set is generated by other people. If I did that I'd rather not to use python dict in that field. Now the problem is here, I'm trying to do some work based on this.

Comment: Unfortunately, `pandas.read_csv()` is a little more demanding about what constitutes an acceptable input file. The `'python'` engine accepts an iterator, but then expects that to be a `csv.reader()` object. Out of time for now.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the dtype parameter to coerce the last column?  Or try using a sep=',{}'.  Shots in the dark, really.

Comment: parse this without the header, then remove the { , }'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the delimiter that `read_csv` uses. If you can change the csv files to use a semicolon for separating columns, you can then use `read_csv(file.csv, sep=';'...)`

Alternatively you can fix the quoting from

```
"001",     "male",    "14",    "{"first":"Mike", "last":"Green"}"
```

to

```
"001",     "male",    "14",    "{'first':'Mike', 'last':'Green'}"
```

Of course both methods mean editing the csv file.

The second looks sounder. The regular expression `(\{[^"]*)(")([^}]*\})` could be used to match quotes inside braces. (untested)